# Chrome Extension Boomerang - SOAP & REST Client - Where are the request files stored in your windows pc?

Tags: rest, soap, boomerang

How to export request files from boomerang soap client ?

Answer (score 0):

You can export current project from project menu (top left corner)

[image: see image here]